# Is it possible to change the address form in Prestashop 1.7 from a module?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a shipping module for Prestashop 1.7.4.4 that will consume a Shipping API I developed. That's why I need to change the default address form.
I know that I can do it manually by editing the address.tpl file or changing the settings at "International > Locations > Countries". That would work if it was on my store, but the module will be available for other customers and it would be great if they don't need to do some extra configurations besides my module's.

Is it possible to do that from my module?

Answer (score 1):

What are the changes you want to make? Are you familiar with Hooks?

It's not really common to modify address form, if you're developing module you have access to many `Hook`s which allows you to modify templates and PrestaShop's Core.

Good read: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

Comment: I'm going to add a new field for County, and separate Address field into Street, Exterior Number, Interior Number, etc.
I could do it by using the override folder, but I don't think it's the best solution.